# Сравнение строк PHP

Tags: поиск, php, sphinx, строки

Задача следующая:
sphinx возвращает массив строк. Он прогоняется через цикл:

```
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {

    //здесь код формирующий строку на выход.

         if(preg_match("#(.*$string.*)#ui",$v)){

    //Если найдено похожее слово, то его выделяем
            $html.="<span style:'red'>$v</span>";
         }
}
```

Проблема в том, что слова в массиве и искомое слово могут различаться по падежам, т.е. разные окончания.
Или может быть частью другого слова.
В этих случаях if не срабатывает.
Можете что-нибудь посоветовать?
**UPD:** Так как sphinx уже сделал аналогичную работу, может кто-нибудь подскажет, как получить из него релевантный данные?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В [документации](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-buildexcerpts) описано решение вашей проблемы.